# Unable to build iOS app using enterprise license in cordova

Tags: ios, ipad, license, enterprise

For a while now, we are developing an app that has to be distributed within the company. We are now reaching the final stage of the development proces and are trying to build for ios with cordova.

That is where the problem occurs, we can't seem to get the building right with our enterprise license. He only accepts our development license, but when I add the enterprise license i get the error: Could not find the codesign identity linked to the provision profile.

We have tried everything that we know, and the only thing we find on the internet is that it has to do something with Keychain Access.

Do some of you have any experience with this?

Thanks